# function to list row number if the cell in a range matches with a key

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table like below.
[image]


Is there any function that returns the list of row numbers that matches with a key passed into the function? An example like below would returns 2 and 6 onto two cells.
function_to_listup("bar", "A1:A6")

If there isn't any built-in function, I would like to achieve it with a local function using google-app-script if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use a simple `FILTER` passing row numbers as the main argument and the condition as the second argument:

```
=FILTER(ROW(A1:A6),A1:A6="bar")
```

If you don't want the filtered numbers in a separate array/cells, you could use a simple `IF` enforcing array context with `ARRAYFORMULA`.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(",", IF(A1:A6="bar",ROW(A1:A6),)))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the built-in function is used.

#### Sample formula:

```
=QUERY({A1:A6,ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A1:A6))},"select Col2 where Col1='bar'")
```

1. Input the range of `A1:A6` and row numbers of `ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A1:A6))`.
2. When the value of `A1:A6` is `bar`, the row number of the same row is returned.

#### Result:

[image]

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the custom function created by Google Apps Script is used. In this case, please put `=function_to_listup("bar", "A1:A6")` to a cell. From your question, it supposes that the range is a1Notation.

#### Sample script:

```
function function_to_listup(searchValue, a1Notation) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getRange(a1Notation);
  const offset = range.getRow();
  const values = range.getValues();
  return values.reduce((ar, [v], i) => {
    if (v == searchValue) ar.push(i + offset);
    return ar;
  }, []);
}
```

- In this case, the result is the same with above sample formula.

### Pattern 3:

In this pattern, the custom function created by Google Apps Script is used. TextFinder is used for this situation. In this case, please put `=function_to_listup("bar", "A1:A6")` to a cell. From your question, it supposes that the range is a1Notation.

#### Sample script:

```
function function_to_listup(searchValue, a1Notation) {
  return SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSheet()
    .getRange(a1Notation)
    .createTextFinder(searchValue)
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .findAll()
    .reduce((ar, r) => ar.concat(r.getRow()), []);
}
```

- In this case, the result is the same with above sample formula.

### References:

- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: thank you very much. I will use the first option with Query. I will come back to the functions using Google App Script later.